# PHP: Sessions never expire

Tags: php, apache, session, ubuntu, session-timeout

Last night I logged in and the following morning I was still logged in, even if I quit my browser. I want the session to expire after a few hours and I thought that it would work with "session.gc_maxlifetime" set to "1440" and "session.cache_expire" set to "180"

Here is what I could find from PHP.ini

```
Session Support                 enabled
Registered save handlers        files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx


session.auto_start        Off
session.bug_compat_42     Off
session.bug_compat_warn   Off
session.cache_expire      180
session.cache_limiter     nocache
session.cookie_domain     no value
session.cookie_httponly   Off
session.cookie_lifetime   0
session.cookie_path       /
session.cookie_secure     Off
session.entropy_file      no value
session.entropy_length    0
session.gc_divisor        1000
session.gc_maxlifetime    1440
session.gc_probability    0
session.hash_bits_per_character  5
session.hash_function     0
session.name              PHPSESSID
session.referer_check     no value
session.save_handler      files
session.save_path         /var/lib/php5
session.serialize_handler php
session.use_cookies       On
session.use_only_cookies  On
session.use_trans_sid     0
```

On our old server we used the same settings and the sessions worked. 
The only difference from the old one is the "session.save_handler" that is set to "memcache" on the old server. Also "session.save_path" is different.

Comment: I personally store the time interval between requests in session. If the interval >= 30 min, I just destroy and recreate session.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Relying on other things and hope them to work is not my thing. :D I think that the best solution would be to implement a session timeout on your own. Use a simple time stamp that denotes the time of the last activity (i.e. request) and update it with every request:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

Updating the session data with every request does also change the session file’s modification date so that the session is not removed by the garbage collector prematurely.

~Foorack

Answer (score 3):

It may help to change `gc_probablity` to something other than 0.

From the manual for `gc_divisor`:

session.gc_divisor coupled with session.gc_probability defines the probability that the gc (garbage collection) process is started on every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using gc_probability/gc_divisor, e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that the GC process starts on each request. session.gc_divisor defaults to 100.

If I'm reading from this right, with gc_probability being 0, the garbage collector is never run, rendering gc_maxlifetime useless.

GC is an expensive process for file-based sessions, so it's not a good idea to run it on every request, [edit: so PHP has a built in randomization to run it periodically]

Addendum:
For anything with real security implications, it's likely better to handle invalidating the session in your script, as Max's answer suggests.  Also `session.cache_expire` sets the default expiration for session pages that are sent to the browser, and doesn't affect session storage at all.

Answer (score -1):

Given you've reset gc_maxlifetime, a couple of things i can think of left to check when this happens:

- PHP needs a restart
- session is recreated/regenerated somewhere